# Select where date is in this year and group by month

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm working on an events page where users can create events and their followers can view the event on their events page.

What I would like to do is select all the events from the table where the event date is within this year (2011), so if the date is `2011-03-30` it will display in the March header, but if it's `2012-03-30` it wont display at all until next year.

So overall, I would like all events to display under headers, e.g. January, February, March.

My table structure is thus:

```
id                             int(11)
event_creator_user_id          int(11)
event_creator_user_username    varchar(255)
event_creator_user_first_name  varchar(255)
event_creator_user_last_name   varchar(255)
event_name                     varchar(255)
event_date                     date
event_time                     time
event_brief_location           varchar(255)
event_location_street          varchar(255)
event_location_town            varchar(255)
event_location_post_code       varchar(255)
event_description              text
event_create_date              datetime
type                           enum('a','b')
```

Comment: I think Treffynnon's approach is pretty good. You can also select the month by using `DATE_FORMAT("%m", event_date)` (i think it's accomplished faster by MySQL than by PHP - plus more convenient/readable in PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the problem. This can be solved by simply getting all the events in the current year using MySQLs [`DATE_FORMAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and ordering the events by date.

Then in PHP you can simply loop over them and when the month changes print out a heading. The code below should make this clearer.

In PHP:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("mydbname");

$SQL = "
    SELECT *,
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`event_date`) AS event_date_timestamp
    FROM events
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y') = 2011
      AND event_date > NOW()
    ORDER BY event_date ASC";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);

$current_month = '';
while ($event = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $month = date('m', $event['event_date_timestamp']);
    if($current_month != $month) {
        $current_month = $month;
        echo '<h1>' . $current_month . '</h1>';
    }
    echo '<p>' . $event['event_name'] . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: don't want to sound ungrateful but that didn't help.

Comment: Why not? If you let me know maybe I can improve it for your situation.

Comment: I'm a newbie to PHP and I'm confused from your whole code. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I have updated the code to be a more complete PHP code snippet. For more information on the mysql_* functions please see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: where did the event_date_timestamp come from?

Comment: I made it by selecting `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date) AS event_date_timestamp`. `AS` allows you to alias a field to a name. In this case I chose `event_date_timestamp` which contains the return value of the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function I used.

Comment: Just to be clear this is not a new column that you need to make in your database table. It is setup at run time! :)

Comment: MAN I LOVE YOU! Thank you ever so much, the only error I came across is you have $SQL in caps and then you stated it in lowercase here $result = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: How could I extend this to only select the dates which haven't already been, like today is the 7th November, and I don't want to get events which were yesterday or two months before. Is this possible?

Comment: I have updated the code to include provision for this. See the `$SQL` has had `AND event_date > NOW()` added to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the year part of the date using a function. Assuming it's MySQL:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   MONTH(event_date) AS 'month'
FROM events
WHERE YEAR(event_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
ORDER BY month ASC
```

Comment: I haven't used MySQL's date structures but after seeing code like this it makes me want to get into it!

Comment: These are nice short cuts. I opted to keep it more verbose to demo more functionality, but this is much easier to read!

Comment: Just a warning though: most functions, like those nifty date functions, are vendor/DBMS specific. The bad: your SQL/code is not portable. The good: less network/traffic overhead (client/server passing around parameters) and fast especially with stored procedures/views. The ugly: these things are dependent on server settings (which you might not have control). Always check the manual and server settings. Your server might be running in a different timezone!

Another advice on date/time handling: It will save you from a lot of trouble if you deal with date/time in ISO format and in UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

In my databases, I store dates as int as the unix timestamp, number of seconds since jan 1 1970.  This way, if I want to select a range (such a just the month of March) i can use `mktime`:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date` > ".mktime(0,0,0,3,1,2011). " AND `date` < ".mktime(0,0,0,4,1,2011));
```

You could loop through months this way:

```
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date` > ".mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,2011). " AND `date` < ".mktime(0,0,0,$i+1,1,2011));
   $monthName = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,2011)); // full name of the month; use "M" for short-name
   // ... your code for printing the events here
}
```

I would help with the `date` data type but I haven't used it.

Comment: You can also use `ORDER BY \`date\` ASC` to get the events in order from first to last.